# Can't mock an imported return value in Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I have a module `random` that exports a few functions. Among them is `shuffle<T>(a: T[]): T[]`. I have to mock it while testing two methods of some other class that internally use it. So, I do:

```ts
jest.mock('./random', async () => {
  const { Foo } = await import('./Foo');

  return {
    ...jest.requireActual('./random'),
    shuffle: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([new Foo()]),
  };
});
```

As `mock()` is hoisted, I have to import `Foo` inside the `mock()`, async way. Unfortunately, when doing actual test I get: `TypeError: (0 , random_1.shuffle) is not a function`. Actually, all of the functions exported from the `random` module are undefined.

Is it because of the async import? If so, how should I import `Foo` to get around the hoisting?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution as I was reviewing the question. So, sharing my knowledge, Q&A style:

Yes, the issue was because of async import. The test was started before the Promise resolved. So, the solution is to place the mock in `beforeAll()`:

```ts
describe('A suite', () => {
  beforeAll(() => {
    jest.mock('./random', async () => {
      const { Foo } = await import('./Foo');

      return {
        ...jest.requireActual('./random'),
        shuffle: jest.fn().mockReturnValue([new Foo()]),
      };
    });
  });

  test(...);
});
```

Jest will await the resolution of the Promise before going on with the tests.